# Adding a method call to a collection

Tags: c#, methods

Given a situation where I have a method `SetFooInDevice()`, which I call using a property as one of the arguments:

```
public class Program
{
    public static byte Foo { get; set; }

    public static void SetFooInDevice(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp, byte foo) 
    {
        var txBuffer = new List<byte>();
        // Format message according to communication protocol
        txBuffer.Add(foo);
        sp.Write(txBuffer.ToArray(), 0, txBuffer.Count);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var _rnd = new Random();
        var _serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
        _serialPort.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Foo = (byte)_rnd.Next(0, 255);
            SetFooInDevice(_serialPort, Foo);  // <-- How to add this call to a collection?
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add the method call to a collection, in a way that the method call can be executed when running through the collection at a later time?

I want to be able to add calls to various methods to a collection, that I can run through and execute later if conditions are met (serial port open, time interval has passed, etc.).

Comment: You mean like an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static byte Foo { get; set; }

public static void SetFooInDevice(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp, byte foo)
{
    var txBuffer = new List<byte>();
    // Format message according to communication protocol
    txBuffer.Add(foo);
    sp.Write(txBuffer.ToArray(), 0, txBuffer.Count);
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<Action> listActions = new List<Action>(); // here you create list of action you need to execute later
    var _rnd = new Random();
    var _serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
    _serialPort.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Foo = (byte)_rnd.Next(0, 255);
        var tmpFoo = Foo; // wee need to create local variable, this is important
        listActions.Add(() => SetFooInDevice(_serialPort, tmpFoo));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    foreach (var item in listActions)
    {
        item(); // here you can execute action you added to collection
    }
}
```

You can check this on MS docs [Using Variance for Func and Action Generic Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/using-variance-for-func-and-action-generic-delegates)

Comment: That's close, but wrong, because `Foo` is overriden every time and when you get to calling this actions - each of them will refer to the last value of `Foo`. You need to use local variable: `var foo = (byte)_rnd.Next(0, 255);`

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at.  Will the Action keep a reference to the property `Foo` and read it at the point of execution, or will it keep `Foo`'s value?

Comment: @Oystein it will keep a reference to property. It will also keep reference to local variable in modified version, but that's fine because every loop iteration it's different variable, so all actions will reference different variables (and so - different values).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks alot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Action` delegate for this purpose like below

```
    private List<Action<System.IO.Ports.SerialPort, byte>> methodCalls
        = new List<Action<System.IO.Ports.SerialPort, byte>>();
```